# Ignorar los datos de un array que están vacíos LARAVEL 5.5

Tags: php, laravel-5

[image: Formulario]

[image: Error campo vacio]

[image: Array]

Buenas a todos,

Mi problema es el siguiente.En el fragmento del formulario siguiente se ven los materiales de la base de datos donde tienes que añadir las unidades a solicitar y marcar la casilla para que haga el insert. El problema está a la hora de dejar un campo sin rellenar , me salta el error de campo vació.
Esto anteriormente no sucedía hasta que añadí las claves foráneas a la tabla productos_pedidos para que al borrar los datos de la table padre estos se eliminen .

En resumen mi duda es saber como hacer para que al estar el campo vacío lo ignore del array y solo haga el insert de los que han sido rellenados y marcados.

Gracias por la ayuda.

```
public function getStore(Request $request)
{
    $nombre=$request->input('nombre');
    $dni=$request->input('dni');
    $telefono=$request->input('telefono');


    Usuarios::firstOrCreate([
        'dni' => $dni
],[
        'nombre'=>$nombre , 
        'telefono'=> $telefono,
]);
    $recogerUsuario =Usuarios::where('dni', $dni)->first();

    $c = new Pedidos;
    $c->id_usuario=$recogerUsuario->id;
    $fecha_entrega=$request->input('fecha_entrega');
    $fecha_devolucion=$request->input('fecha_devolucion');
    $fecha1= DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y' ,$fecha_entrega);
    $fecha2= DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y' ,$fecha_devolucion);
    $c->fecha_entrega=$fecha1->format('Y-m-d');
    $c->fecha_devolucion=$fecha2->format('Y-m-d');
    $c->descripcion=$request->input('descripcion');
    $c->save();

    $datab= Input::get('cantidad');
    $data=$request->seleccion;
    $id_pedido=Pedidos::where('id_usuario',$recogerUsuario->id)->orderBy('id','DESC')->first();


    $id_producto=Stock::where('id',$data)->get();
        for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++){
            $b=new ProductosPedidos;
            $b->id_pedido=$id_pedido->id;
            $b->id_producto=$data[$i];
            $b->cantidad=$datab[$i];
            $b->save();
        }
    return redirect('/detalles');
}
```

Comment: Mejor su nos muestras el error. No queda claro si es cosa de validate o de la base de datos

Comment: He añadido la imagen del error. Es en el array cantidad, no logro que el valor en blanco no sea recogido

Comment: Debes editar tu tabla y permitir que cantidad sea nulo o  que por defecto sea cero, por otro lado supongo que no tiene sentido guardar un registro con cantidad 0, si nos muestras el controlador donde haces la inserción quizá te podamos dar una respuesta más completa, para no insertar registros sin valor

Comment: Fue lo primero que pensé, pero después me quedaba una tabla enorme ya que en la imagen solo se ven 3 pero habrá muchos más productos

Comment: Puedes crear un `if` dentro del `for` para comprobar si la cantidad es diferente a cero, si es diferente creas el registro en caso contrario no haces nada.